# What is the name of the identity $\text{Area}=\frac 1 2 \int x'y-y'x\ dt$?

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry

Where $(x(t), y(y))$ for $t\in[0, 1]$ is some sufficiently nice closed curve (possibly it has to be convex), the area enclosed by the curve is given by

$$\frac 1 2 \int_0^1 x'(t)y(t) - x(t)y'(t)\ dt$$

I've seen this identity used before in lecture notes and also come up with an informal geometric proof of it, but I can't find any reference to it online. What is its name?

Comment: I don't think it has a name. It often comes up in the context of Green's theorem in the plane. Actually it also follows from the formula for the area of a plane region whose boundary is given using polar coordinates. $r(t)^2=x(t)^2+y(t)^2$ and $\phi(t)=\arctan (y(t)/x(t))$ combine nicely to produce this because $\phi'(t)=(x y'- x' y)/(x^2+y^2)$. But I don't think it has a name based on that connection either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it has no *name*.

You can find it in the do Carmo's *Differential geometry of curves and surfaces*, in the chapter **Global Properties of Plane Curves**, section **A. The Isoperimetric Inequality**. In the edition I have, page 32.

Comment: From the work you are citing, p. 33: *We shall mention, however, that Eq (1) can also be obtained by using Stokes' (Green's) theorem in the plane (see Exercise 15).*  I could respect anyone just calling it "A corollary of Green's theorem" then.

Comment: If you consider that a *name* for the formula, then I agree.

Comment: It certainly beats "formula with no name on page 32 of do Carmo's book " :) (I'm not trying to criticize anything you've written, I'm just joking. This is already a very helpful answer and I've upvoted it) But you're right, it's not as snappy or namelike as "(someone's) formula".

Comment: He asked for name and reference. That's what I gave. What you suggest instead is a common name, which is the best you can get for something without a given name.

Comment: I agree with all of that! (and already did, even before this explanation!)